# Error while creating qcow2 file using qemu-img

Tags: 12.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

When I am creating an qcow2 file using qemu-img command I am getting error as librbd.so.1 file not found. When I check for the dependencies that .so file is present in the /usr/lib folder.

Can any one solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

First try to install this library if not exists:

```
sudo apt-get install librbd1
```

then try you `qemu-img` command. If failed find the library location:

```
sudo find / -name  librbd.so.1
```

make a symlink to it

```
ln -s /usr/lib/librbd.so.1 /path/to/your/librd.so.1
```

then execute `qemu-img` again

Comment: Where is the 'LDFLAGS' varible present? In which file this variable have to keep and what is the location of file?